# How to obtain a link to the source file on docsify's website

Tags: docsify

I deployed a docsify project using Cloudflare. On the index. HTML of the webpage, I linked JavaScript and CSS files in the same directory. However, when I loaded the webpage, the link returned an HTML document rendered by docsify instead of the original JavaScript file. How can I make it return the original JavaScript and CSS files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing a problem statement, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [Edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

docsify doesn't handle static files, you may just be accessing the wrong path.